# How to make a grid drag and drop like in google keep

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, drag-and-drop

I am trying to accomplish a drag and drop section like in google keep, in vuejs,
where every div can be in a different height(all in the same width)

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFk3r.png)

Searched google, used a library that didn't work well, nothing like the quality of google keep

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with jquery UI. It is high quality.
There is the drag and drop api in jquery ui.

You just need to include a jquery library and jquery ui library. Vuejs is more advanced than what you need to do.

Library links:

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
      }
    });
  } );
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>
 
<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>
```

[Documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/)

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear enough, this needs to be in an existing project that is built on Vuejs, which means I can use jquery it, thank you for you comment